# Creating a online photo editor in Python

Tags: python, image, photo, editing

I am going to build an online photo editor using python, but I don't know how to start. My plan is to create a platform online. Users can upload their photos and the system can transform their photos into a style like Ukioyoe from Japan, the ancient wood printing, so the photo outcomes are similar to that. Is there any similar works that have already done or any libraries that can help to do this work?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/) (ex PIL)

I like to use [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/)

Comment: I have taken a look on scikit-image. I found that they are only taking images from the data folder in their pack on my computer, but I can't use an URL to replace the image code, like "image.png" to "http://xxxxxxxx". Is there any method to solve that?

Comment: You can use. For example Flask:

import skimage
image_data = request.files['image_data']
image = skimage.io.imread(image_data)

Comment: I see. I will try to work with it. But sorry that I have one more question, is it possible if I wanna delete the toolbar and the grid, just the picture is on the viewer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Online photo editor means that most of the processing will be done on the client side (i.e. in browser). Python is mostly a server-side language, so I would suggest using some other, more browser-friendly, language (perhaps, JavaScrip?)

Comment: I see. So is it hard if I link my python code with HTML and then process the data uploaded from the user to my server, and my server gives back response to HTML? Like users click button and it will transfer to another page.

Comment: First scenario: Photoshop/Gimp-like editor: You can not built in Python code into HTML; if you send data back and forth for every user interaction, it will be subject to network latency plus processing time (PIL or whatever) which means unusable

Comment: Second scenario: specific set of operations applied to an image, e.g. convert to black and white or apply smoothing; separate page for every such operation; relatively long processing time (up to couple seconds). In this case server side processing is fine and @StanislavFilin's suggestions are correct